# Update a public string from protected

Tags: c#, .net

I want to make this string `public`. i.e., available from other functions. How can I do that?

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{   
    String parameter = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];   
}
```

Comment: No you can't, the string `parameter` can only be accessed to in your function `OnNavigatedTo`. If you want to use it you should declare the `parameter` outside the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it outside of the function (global scope).

Something like:

```
String parameter="";
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{   
    parameter = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];   
}
```

Now you can use the string `parameter` any where in that file.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String parameter = new String();
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e){

    String parameter = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];

}
```

You just need to change the scope of your variable to global :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be that you move it outside the function, but make it private, then expose it via a public property; for example:

```
private string _parameter;
public string Parameter
{
    get { return _parameter;}
    set
    {
        _parameter = value;
    }
}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{   
    _parameter = NavigationContext.QueryString["parameter"];   
}
```

If you only need to access it from within the current class, but outside of the function then you can leave out the property, or even make it read-only.  Alternatively, you could use the implicit property definition:

```
public string Parameter { get; set; }
```

And with C# 6 you will be able to use [initializers](https://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2014/04/04/c-6-first-reactions.aspx) with this.